как добавить в файл в который парсит grep текст дату парсинга
что нужно добавить в эту команду что бы создавалась дата парсинга
grep "отрывок из текста" "$HOME/$APPS" >> $1


Пусть имеем текстовый файл, p.txt:
PING 9.9.9.9 (9.9.9.9) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 9.9.9.9: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=67.1 ms
64 bytes from 9.9.9.9: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=67.2 ms
64 bytes from 9.9.9.9: icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=67.1 ms
64 bytes from 9.9.9.9: icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=67.1 ms
64 bytes from 9.9.9.9: icmp_seq=5 ttl=57 time=67.3 ms

--- 9.9.9.9 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 67.163/67.231/67.369/0.245 ms


grep 64 p.txt | awk '{print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0}'

Вывод
grep 64 p.txt | awk '{print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0}'
2024-10-16 10:59:15 64 bytes from 9.9.9.9: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=67.1 ms
2024-10-16 10:59:15 64 bytes from 9.9.9.9: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=67.2 ms
2024-10-16 10:59:15 64 bytes from 9.9.9.9: icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=67.1 ms
2024-10-16 10:59:15 64 bytes from 9.9.9.9: icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=67.1 ms
2024-10-16 10:59:15 64 bytes from 9.9.9.9: icmp_seq=5 ttl=57 time=67.3 ms


что тут не так ?         grep "акамулятор" "$HOME/$APPS" | awk 'print strftime("%x-%R:%S:%N")' >> $1

разобрался, спасибо!

что то grep наносекунды не хочет парсить вроде одно и то же

а на openwrt вообще даты нет я уже и awk установил, но не в какую

@KostyaKozhan, вам помог данный ответ? Если да, то его стоит принять — так вы покажите другим, что ответ полезен

все вижу принять не вижу, проголосовать не могу не хватает репутации
